# Microsoft Graph SDK (C#) Group Mailbox

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a connected console application that I'm writing to help automate an upcoming tenant migration.

What I'm looking to do is remove all associations of the custom domains from our current tenant so I can add them to a new tenant.

What I have so far:

ConsoleApp is registered with AAD and API permissions have been assigned and granted consent.

I've imported the following:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client
```

Initialized a `graphClient`:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

And successfully made `.GetAsync` calls to the Graph.

What I need help with:

I'm trying to update a Group's email to `'gItem.mailNickname@tenantID'`. I've got an error saying that the "Mail field is read-only". Thru the Graph Explorer, I noticed that the `proxyAddresses` field includes all the aliases for the group and that the Mail is listed as "SMPT:..." I'm trying to overwrite the `proxyAddresses` field with

```
var upGroup = await graphClient
    .Groups["4f629be4-f592-4520-b80d-7570f68e276e"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var updateFields = new Group
{
    ProxyAddresses = new List<string>()
    {
    "SMPT:" + upGroup.MailNickname + "@" + tenantID,
    }
};

await graphClient
    .Groups[upGroup.Id]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(updateFields);
```

I get the error that there are insufficient permissions but have checked AAD to ensure that `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `Groups.ReadWrite.All` are both provisioned and granted.

Other Group properties are able to be altered which leads me to question my structure on the `proxyAddresses` property.

Failed Code to add to the list

```
var updateFields = new Group
{
    ProxyAddresses = new string[] { "SMTP:" + upGroup.MailNickname + "@" + tenantID }
};
```

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace RemoveGroupAliases
{

    class Program
    {
        private static string clientId = "";
        private static string tenantID = "";
        private static string clientSecret = "";
        private static IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        static ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var groups = await graphClient
                .Groups
                .Request()
                .Filter("mailEnabled+eq+true")
                .GetAsync();

            foreach (var tgroup in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tgroup.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(tgroup.DisplayName);
            };

            var upGroup = await graphClient
                .Groups["4f629be4-f592-4520-b80d-7570f68e276e"]
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            var updateFields = new Group
            {
                ProxyAddresses = new List<String>()
                {
                "SMTP:" + upGroup.MailNickname + "@" + tenantID
                }
            };

            await graphClient
                .Groups[upGroup.Id]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(updateFields);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to pull all mail-enabled groups and remove all domains so I can remove it from this tenant and associate it to a new tenant. I'll have a different program to assign the domains and aliases once the domains are switched over. When I hover over the tooltip for `proxyAddresses` one of the last lines says "Read-Only" which may be my issue but I'm not getting that as the error.

Comment: Proxyaddress can only accept one 'SMTP' address, all the other addresses need to be 'smtp'. Is it possible that's your issue?

Comment: I'm to replace the entire field value at first. Even with the corrected SMTP a CreateAsync (Post) gets an error that the target does not allow the HTTP method.

Comment: I've gone thru and created a new App Registration and made sure it had the Admin Consent green checkmarks before moving on in testing.

```var updateFields = new Group
            {
                ProxyAddresses = new List<String>
                {
                    "SMTP:test.permissions@lonestarsecure.com",
                    "smtp:test.permissions@5DShield.com"
                }
            };

            await graphClient.Groups[upGroup.Id]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(updateFields);```
Still no luck

Comment: Update: The console program is successful at updating the description field which leads me to believe that the issue lies with building the construct for the ProxyAddresses field.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post a pastebin of the entire HTTP request, including the JSON? (don't forget to redact any private keys etc.)

Comment: Updated Full Code Above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario you're describing simply isn't possible. You cannot detach a Group (or really any data) from one tenant and migrate it to another. Every AAD tenant is a distinct entity and isolated from any other tenant.

Microsoft Graph uses the token you provide to route your requests to the correct API/Service within the tenant that generated the token. You cannot have a single token connected to multiple tenants.

Also, as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), the properties `mail` and `proxyAddresses` are read-only. If you wish to change the group's email alias, you *can* change the `mailNickname` property. This is simply the "alias" for the Group, the domain portion of the email address is automatically assigned by AAD and Exchange (`{mailNickname}@{default.tenant.domain}`).

Comment: Okay, I wasn't getting the error that the field was read-only when I would run my script. I was able to figure out the powershell to automate it. I'm simply trying to remove all the custom domains from my current tenant and using a second script/console app assign the custom domains to new users/groups in a new tenant.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You don't need to do any of that. Simply add and validate the domain in the tenant and it will automatically handle assigning the added domain to each alias. The same goes for removing them from their current tenants. The only restriction is that you cannot remove the original `{name}.onmicrosoft.com` domain or the Default domain (assuming it is different origonal domain).

Comment: Hey Thanks, I had a meeting with a company about doing a migration and they were telling me that the cut-over would take about 2 days of hunt and Powershell to get domains removed and added to the new tenant. I see that the Admin portal will unassign domains when you remove them from the tenant.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would take 2 days but I'm not aware of any limitation in O365 that would cause this. You may need to wait for the removal to propagate before  adding the domain to another tenant but that shouldn't take very long.